# I want to interchange two words in a given java file

Tags: java, string, file

I want to interchange the last 2 words in a java file.
The file is called text_d.txt and it contains:

```
   Student learns programming java.
```

and this is the code(below).The output is the same and I don't understand why it does not change.

```
import java.nio.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class Test3 {
     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
         String s2="text_t.txt";
         File _newf = new File("text_d.txt");
         changeOrder(_newf);
     }

     public static void changeOrder(File f) throws Exception {
         FileInputStream _inp=new FileInputStream(f.getAbsolutePath());
         BufferedReader _rd=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(_inp));
         String _p=_rd.readLine();

         while (_p != null) {
             String [] _b = _p.split(" ");
             for(int i = 0; i <= _b.length; i++) {
                 if(i == 2) {
                     String aux=_b[i];
                     _b[i]=_b[i+1];
                     _b[i+1]=aux;
                     break;
                 }
              }
              _p=_rd.readLine();
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @atishshimpi  the expected output is Student learns java programming

Comment: Do you want to change the order of words, in the file? right now you just changed their order in the "_b" array, you did not saved changes to the file anywhere.

Comment: You do not output anything anywhere. You read the lines into memory and then you manipulate the memory. The file is not changed.

Comment: @AliLotfi yes you are right,to change its content i have to write the array in the file again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reading, interchanging and writing the file, I suggest you to do something like this:

```
public class Test3 {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
     String s2="text_t.txt";
     File _newf = new File("text_d.txt");
     changeOrder(_newf);
 }

 public static void changeOrder(File f) throws Exception {
     FileInputStream _inp = new FileInputStream(f.getAbsolutePath());
     BufferedReader _rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(_inp));

     ArrayList<String[]> newFileContent = new ArrayList<String[]>();
     String _p=_rd.readLine();
     while (_p != null) {
         String [] _b = _p.split(" ");
         String temp = _b[_b.length - 2];
         _b[_b.length - 2] = _b[_b.length - 1];
         _b[_b.length - 1] = temp;
         newFileContent.add(_b);

          _p=_rd.readLine();
     }

     PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(f.getAbsolutePath(), "UTF-8");
     for (String[] line : newFileContent) {
         for (String word : line) {
             writer.print(word);
         }
         writer.println();
    }
    writer.close();
}
```

There is two minor changes:

- First I changed the `for` loop you used in your code, with 3 lines of code.
- Second I used to add all of lines which changed in the `while` loop in an `ArrayList` of `String` arrays which could hold changes in order to save on the file in the future.

And after all, I used an instance of `PrintWriter` class which could write a file on the hard disk. and in a `foreach` loop, I wrote contents of new file on the input file.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
public static void changeOrder(File f) throws Exception {
    FileInputStream _inp = new FileInputStream(f.getAbsolutePath());
    BufferedReader _rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(_inp));
    String _p = _rd.readLine();
    while (_p != null) {
        String [] _b=_p.split(" ");
        String temp  = _b[_b.length - 1];
        _b[_b.length - 1] = _b[_b.length - 2];
        _b[_b.length - 2] = temp;
        _p = _rd.readLine();
    }

}
```

But if you want the file to be updated you need to write the results to the file...You should use something to write to the file like a `PrintWriter`.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick You want:

```
public static String changeOrder(File fileName) throws IOException {
    Scanner file = new Scanner(fileName);
    String line = file.nextLine();
    line = line.replace('.', ' ');
    String[] items = line.split(" ");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(items[0] + " ");
    sb.append(items[1] + " ");
    sb.append(items[3] + " ");
    sb.append(items[2] + ".");
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Expected result: Student learns java programming.